# CakePHP Saving a new normalized HABTM model and using it in the resolved table

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

So quick overview of what I'm trying to do. User hasMany `BusinessUnitsUser`. `BusinessUnit` hasMany `BusinessUnitUser`.

In this manner, I've normalized their relationship to two hasManys (I hate working with HABTM related data).

On a new user form, I'd like to give the user the option of adding a new Business Unit at the same time.

Currently, my `$this->request->data` array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [title] => Mr
            [first_name] => Kyle
            [last_name] => O'Brien
            [username] => 55546@mylife.unisa.ac.za
            [producing_office_id] => 4
        )

    [BusinessUnit] => Array
        (
            [name] => lskfjsldkfjsdlfk
        )

)
```

Now, this is obviously incorrect, but I'm struggling to think of how to resolve this. I thought giving you a visual of the array, you might be able to tell me what my array should look like.

Here's my relationship array in `BusinessUnitsUser`:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'BusinessUnit' => array(
            'className' => 'BusinessUnit',
            'foreignKey' => 'business_unit_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

**EDIT (thanks ndm)**

Note the goal: I'm adding a user and I may or may not be adding `BusinessUnitsUser` associations as well but I'm definitely also going to be adding a new `BusinessUnit` - the form for which exists on the new_user form.

Currently, the `User` is saving with a `$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)` but NOT the new `BusinessUnit` and certainly not the new `BusinessUnitsUser` entry (which I expect to contain the new user id and the new business unit id.

Comment: What makes you think that the given format is incorrect (it's not, given that I understood your setup correctly)? What's the actual problem?

Comment: @ndm - well saving this data in a $this->User->saveAll($this->request->data); yeilds a newly saved user but no new entry for the BusinessUnit model and no new entry for the BusinessUnitsUser entry (which would have the new user_id and the new business_unit_id generated)

Comment: Ok, I see, please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Save via the join table model

The solution should be pretty simple, for that type of association you'll have to save via the join table model (even if you don't save additional data on the that table):

```
$this->User->BusinessUnitsUser->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
```

See also **[http://book.cakephp.org/.../saving-your-data.html#saving-hasmany-through-data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-hasmany-through-data)**

That way the ORM can properly save the `belongsTo` associated data, and create an appropriate record in the join table, using foreign key values obtained from the save operations for the associated data.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to get back to you. The genius I am, I messed up my Ubuntu install for like the millionth time by accidentally setting a sudo chmod -R on my var folder. Sigh. Anyway, this works like a charm. Thanks so much!